# GPS Suggestions

Tags: gps

I have decided to play in the world of GPS modules. I have read the [GPS Buying Guide](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/tutorial_info.php?tutorials_id=127) from Sparkfun, but still am not sure which unit I want to go with. I am leaning toward the [LS20031](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=8975), do any of you have any experience with GPS modules? Any advice you would like to add to the chiphacker community?

Comment: might want to give a bit more info on your application ?

Comment: Mostly just curiosity. I know many of our students have had issues finding one that can get a lock inside a building. I know buildings are difficult to get locks in, but my Garmin GPS is able to get a lock in the same room. So, not looking for high accuracy or refresh rate, just something that can have reception that is about the same as commercial products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently purchased a couple of GPS modules for a project I'm working on.  You didn't specifically mention Arduino, but I bought the [GPS logger shield](http://www.adafruit.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=17_21&products_id=98) from Adafruit with an EM-406a module.  I'm not using an Arduino, but I figured it was a compact solution that had two things I wanted (GPS and removable storage).  The EM-406a had no problems getting a satellite lock inside my office.  I also got the [Copernicus DIP Module](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=8146) from Sparkfun so I could breadboard with it. No problems so far - just read the datasheet and remember to pull XRESET and XSTANDBY high.

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to get a lock inside your office. I am going to look into these. I actually use PICs and MSP430s. Around this community it seems as though many people use Arduinos.

Answer (score 5):

[u-blox](http://www.u-blox.com/) makes the best ones, but they are expensive. They are used by the military and government agencies because of their performance. I didn't have any problems with one of their modules on a home-made PCB, interfaced to a 16F88 PIC. It works indoors.

Answer (score 0):

There's lots of detail about building a GPS to SD Card Logger [here](http://www.gedanken.demon.co.uk/gps-sd-logger/). It uses a PIC but you may be able to make alterations as you want.